# New 20.04 install and now I cannot see my Seagate external NAS drive

Tags: 20.04, external-hdd, nas

Tried a few basic things but to no solution. Not that tech-geeky when it comes to Linus (just use it).

Checked all files up to date and I can see the drive using my Win10 laptop so I know it is fine and working with the data there

Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question with details of what you have tried in terms of attempting to mount the NAS including your fstab entry or command from the terminal.

Comment: well I did do a search... found a couple of maybe related things about Samba, but did not work .... as I said, I am not a guru unix hacker - but since this worked fine on Ubuntu 14.04 (I know I kept it too ong), I kind of thought it would still work

Answer (score 0):

Open Files -> click on other locations - if listed you will need to provide any credentials

consider configuring fstab with the network address for a permanently available share

EDIT from your additional information this may be a permissions problem for your mount point. Do you have any details for this

Can you confirm you have samba installed + nautilus-share

Comment: I can 'see' the external drive .. and see the public folder (where all my files are) but when it tries to open I get nothing